# Give permission to network service

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-service

I would very much appreciate some help because I am stuck with this problem for a while now. I am trying to do what is outlined in this answer:
[please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978054/cannot-start-windows-service-in-networkservice-account/11983513#11983513)

But in those steps, I don't know how to perform Step 3:

> Add > "NETWORK SERVICE" > OK

This is the dialog I get:

[Screenshot](http://i58.tinypic.com/264tgmw.jpg)

Hence I don't know how to add Network Service on this dialog. Can someone please help and explain me how to do this? I am really stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

On your screenshot you have

> Enter the object names to select (examples):

so into that input box just below this text, simply type

```
NETWORK SERVICE
```

and then click OK.